# Find the sum of a mathematical series

Tags: c

> Write a program in C to find the sum of the series [ 1-X^2/2!+X^4/4!- .........]
>
> Test Data:
>
> ```
> Input the Value of x :2  
> Input the number of terms : 5
> ```
>
> Expected Output:
>
> ```
> the sum = -0.415873
> Number of terms = 5
> ```

Here is the code I wrote, no compilation error, I just wasnt getting the answer right:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    float sum=0;
    float ans;
    int c, y, fac=1;
    int a,i, x=2;
    float z;
    for (i = 1; i<=2; i++)
    {
        a= 2*i;
        y = pow(2,a);
        for (c = 1; c<=a; c++)
        {
            fac= fac*c;
        }
        z = (float) y/fac;
        if (i%2 == 0) {
            sum = sum + z;
        }
        else{
            sum = sum - z;
        }
    }

    ans = 1 + sum;
    printf("The answer is %f" , ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you suspect the problem is? Have you done any debugging to narrow it down? If not, try running your program in a debugger or inserting debugging printouts to see the values of the intermediate calculations and figure out where it's going wrong.

Comment: I am not getting the value of variable 'z' cporrect for some reason

Comment: Trace it backwards. Are `y` and `fac` correct?

Comment: You wrote what you expect. What do you get instead?

Comment: `fac` is wrong.  You initialize it to `1`, once, outside the main loop.  Then, each time through the main loop, you multiply it by `a!`.  So you aren't getting `a!`.  You're getting `2!*4!*...*a!`.

Comment: I don't see your Number of terms = 5 anywhere in your program.

Comment: The assignment is not clear because what would be the next term? `X^8/8!` or `X^6/6!`?

Answer (score 0):

1. You didn't used number of terms.
2. You didn't set fac to 1 to the end of the for.
3. y is equal to pow(x,a) not pow(2,a).
4. Int can store numbers between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647, so I recommend to use long long (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807). And also, double instead of float. You can take a look here for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=msvc-160.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
double sum=0;
double ans;
long long c, y, fac=1;
long long a,i, x=2, numberOfTerms = 5;
float z;
for (i = 1; i<= numberOfTerms; i++)
{
 a= 2*i;
y = pow(x,a);
 for (c = 1; c<=a; c++)
  {
   fac= fac*c;
 }
 z = (double) y/fac;
 if (i%2 == 0) {
  sum = sum + z;
}
 else{
   sum = sum - z;
 }
 
 fac = 1;

}

ans = 1 + sum;
printf("The answer is %f" , ans);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: when you answer, try to format your code. In this for it deserves DV

Comment: everywhere use double. Do not use `float` if not necessary (for example uCs). do not calculate on integers only double

Comment: *"Int can store numbers between"* - That's usually the case, but it's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use functions.
2. If you do not have to, do not use `float`. Use double for floating point calculations.
3. Your code does not reflect the formula at all.

```
double fact(unsigned n)
{
    double result = 1.0;

    for(unsigned x = 1; x <= n; x++)
        result *= x;
    return result;
}

double series(double x, unsigned nterms)
{
    double result = 1;
    for(unsigned term = 1; term <= nterms; term++)
    {
        result += (1.0 - ((term & 1) << 1)) * pow(x, (double)term * 2.0) / fact(term * 2);
    }
    return result;
}


int main(void)
{
    for(unsigned nterms = 2; nterms < 20; nterms++)
    {
        printf("nterms = %2u series(4) = %.32f\n", nterms, series(4.0, nterms));
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8c3xM4